# Multi threading with 3rd party headerfiles in Borland C++ 5.02

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, console-application, borland-c++

Is there any header files or extension that I can use to make multi thread on Borland 5.02?

I want to make a program that animates two lines going in different speed, in an infinite loop.
 Something like this

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include<dos.h>


void linesmov(int seconds);

main()
{
// Thread 1
linesmov(5);

//Thread 2
linesmov(30);
}

void linesmov(int mseconds){

    int i=0;
while (true){
    i=i+1;
    clrscr();   // Or system("cls"); If you may...
    gotoxy(i,15);   cout << "____||____||____";
    Sleep(mseconds);
    if (i>115){     i=0;  }
}

}
```

Yes.. I know that people are going to go and say, GET A NEW COMPILER,
My school uses old compiler as a "standard" on scoring, so please bear with me.

Comment: In case you are wondering why schools use old applications, they thought using older systems and stuff means easier to implant the basics. A **stereotypical** _thought_ I guess..

Comment: If that's the reason they gave you, they're lying like a cheap rug. They use ancient tools because (a) in many cases they're dirt cheap/free to license, and equally important, they can run on ancient *hardware*. Ex: You can run Turbo C on an 8088 from thirty years ago. You're nuts to *want to*, but you could.

Comment: Yeah.. I know. Probably they are just too lazy to update their software and their system. But that's not the point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Boehm wrote a famous paper on why that's a bad idea: [Threads cannot be implemented as a library](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-209.pdf).

In a nutshell, if you want to do multi-threaded programming, you need a language and a compiler that give certain guarantees with regards to thread-safety. If you do not have this, you will run into very weird and hard to understand bugs eventually.

This was by the way one of the main reasons why thread support introduced with C++11 was such a big deal: Just using a library is not enough, you actually need proper support from the language as well.

Since Borland C++ does not give these guarantees, do not expect it to carry you very far when using it for multi-threaded programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `windows.h`, which means you have access to the Win32 API. So have a look at the Win32 [`CreateThread()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374779.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally found one way to do this.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void linesmov(int mseconds,int y);


void linesmov(int mseconds,int y){

    int i=0;
while (true){
    i=i+1;
     // Or system("cls"); If you may...
    gotoxy(i,y);   cout << "____||____||____"; gotoxy(i-1,y);cout << " ";
    Sleep(mseconds);
    if (i>115){     i=0;  for(int o=0;o<100;o++){gotoxy(0,y);   cout << "                  ";}}
}
}

DWORD WINAPI mythread1(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    printf("Thread inside %d \n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    linesmov(5,10);
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI mythread2(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    printf("Thread inside %d \n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    linesmov(30,15);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE myhandle1;
    DWORD mythreadid1;
    HANDLE myhandle2;
    DWORD mythreadid2;
    myhandle1 = CreateThread(0,0,mythread1,0,0,&mythreadid1);
    myhandle2 = CreateThread(0,0,mythread2,0,0,&mythreadid2);
    printf("Thread after %d \n", mythreadid1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Well done!